# Why do we use CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs

I want encryption code in AES-256 for that I need key into 256bits only right ? For the same I have written the code as follow:

```
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("c79109c462c34441840551e2ba79830e");
var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key, { iv: iv }); 
var encryptedData = iv.concat(encrypted.ciphertext)
console.log("encrypted data: ", encryptedData.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
```

Here, I have encrypted 'hello world' text .Why do we need to use CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse for this?

Comment: Because your using a `key` & `iv`, and the key needs to be a `WordArray`,  and not a string.

Comment: I am passing a 32-byte hexadecimal string 'c79109c462c34441840551e2ba79830e', which is in 128 bits, Using CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse() on a 32-byte hexadecimal string will convert into 256 bits, which can be used as the key for AES256 encryption right? please correct me if i am wong

Comment: You need a 32 bytes key for AES-256. An Utf-8 encoding of the string `c79109c462c34441840551e2ba79830e` is *one* way to create such a 32 bytes sequence. CryptoJS provides the `Utf8` encoder for this purpose. Keys generated this way have a reduced value range of 16 instead of 256 values per byte. The full range of 256 values is possible with the `Hex` encoder where 64 hex digits are required for a 32 bytes key, s. [Encoders](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders).

Comment: In short, your premise is wrong, you should never need `Utf8.parse` *for a key*. The key should not be a character string, unless it is hex or base 64 encoded. You could use it to convert your message to binary, but that's about it when it comes to cryptography.